# Android Gradle build failure because of obfuscated external jar

Tags: android, gradle, build

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':jarName:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not expand ZIP 'C:\drive\projects\work\2netSampleApp_2netMobileCore\libs\2net-mobile-core-release.jar'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.visit(ZipFileTree.java:99)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:109)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTreeImpl.visit(AbstractFileTree.java:135)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.DefaultJarSnapshotter.createSnapshot(DefaultJarSnapshotter.java:44)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.DefaultJarSnapshotter.createSnapshot(DefaultJarSnapshotter.java:39)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.CachingJarSnapshotter$1.create(CachingJarSnapshotter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.CachingJarSnapshotter$1.create(CachingJarSnapshotter.java:41)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.DefaultJarSnapshotCache$2.create(DefaultJarSnapshotCache.java:56)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.DefaultJarSnapshotCache$2.create(DefaultJarSnapshotCache.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.cache.MinimalPersistentCache.get(MinimalPersistentCache.java:66)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.DefaultJarSnapshotCache.get(DefaultJarSnapshotCache.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.DefaultJarSnapshotCache.get(DefaultJarSnapshotCache.java:32)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.CachingJarSnapshotter.createSnapshot(CachingJarSnapshotter.java:41)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.JarClasspathSnapshotFactory.createSnapshot(JarClasspathSnapshotFactory.java:40)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.JarClasspathSnapshotMaker.maybeInitialize(JarClasspathSnapshotMaker.java:60)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.jar.JarClasspathSnapshotMaker.storeJarSnapshots(JarClasspathSnapshotMaker.java:42)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:46)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
      at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:157)
      at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:127)
      at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:49)
      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
      ... 14 more

---

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy zip entry C:\drive\projects\work\SampleApp\SampleCore\libs\my_lib.jar!com/demo/
demo1/a/b/DUMP.class to 'C:\drive\projects\work\SampleApp\SampleCore\build\tmp\expandedArchives\my_lib.jar_2q5x1be7tzirmbxnnkctt4jwl\a\b

---

Back Ground Info :

Environment : Windows

I have a Jar which is obfuscated by the proguard and it have multiple files with the same name but with different case.

For Example :

Package demo
----------> A.class
----------> a.class

Gradle is trying to expand ZIP by unzipping the jar. But windows is not able to keep the same file (With the same name but in different case) in a single directory.